# AVAssetsWriter frame rate

Tags: ios

I used followed codes to encode a video with several local pictures. but the problem is I have 30 pictures, and only get 1 second video, is there any way to get the video with 30 seconds and 24 frame rate?

```
- (BOOL)encodeReadySamplesFromOutput:(AVAssetReaderOutput *)output toInput:(AVAssetWriterInput *)input
{
    NSLog(@"Frame init m == %d",m);
    while (input.isReadyForMoreMediaData)
    {
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
        if (sampleBuffer)
        {
            BOOL handled = NO;
            BOOL error = NO;

            CMItemCount count;
            CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sampleBuffer, 0, nil, &count);
            CMSampleTimingInfo *timingInfo = malloc(sizeof(CMSampleTimingInfo) * count);
            CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sampleBuffer, count, timingInfo, &count);

            for (CMItemCount i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                timingInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;
                timingInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeMake(m, 24);
//                timingInfo[i].duration = CMTimeMake(1, 12);
            }

            CMSampleBufferRef completedSampleBuffer;
            CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, count, timingInfo, &completedSampleBuffer);
            free(timingInfo);

            if (self.reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatusReading || self.writer.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting)
            {
                handled = YES;
                error = YES;
            }

            if (!handled && self.videoOutput == output)
            {
                // update the video progress
                ++m;

                NSLog(@"Frame m == %d",m);
                lastSamplePresentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(completedSampleBuffer);
                CMTimeValue value = lastSamplePresentationTime.value;
                CMTimeScale scale = lastSamplePresentationTime.timescale;

                NSLog(@"Frame value == %lld", value);
                NSLog(@"Frame scale == %d",scale);
                self.progress = duration == 0 ? 1 : CMTimeGetSeconds(lastSamplePresentationTime) / duration;

                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(exportSession:renderFrame:withPresentationTime:toBuffer:)])
                {
                    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(completedSampleBuffer);
                    CVPixelBufferRef renderBuffer = NULL;
                    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, self.videoPixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool, &renderBuffer);
                    [self.delegate exportSession:self renderFrame:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:lastSamplePresentationTime toBuffer:renderBuffer];
                    if (![self.videoPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:renderBuffer withPresentationTime:lastSamplePresentationTime])
                    {
                        error = YES;
                    }
                    CVPixelBufferRelease(renderBuffer);
                    handled = YES;
                }
            }
            if (!handled && ![input appendSampleBuffer:completedSampleBuffer])
            {
                error = YES;
            }
            CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
            CFRelease(completedSampleBuffer);
            if (error)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [input markAsFinished];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you get a lot more pictures or repeat the ones you have.

In either case, you're going to have to calculate presentation time yourself, with something like `CMTimeMake(m, 24)`, e.g.:

```
[self.videoPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:renderBuffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(m, 24)];
```

If you dropped the 24fps requirement (why do you need that?) you could get a 30second video, of 30 images at 1fps by using `CMTimeMake(m, 1)` instead in `appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:`.

Comment: But the 1fps video can not be played on windows vlc - -

Comment: In that case you'll have to add each image 24 times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, add each image means appendPixelBuffer?